# Stream Object is empty using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I Have this Server:

```
    let app = require("express")();
    let ss = require("socket.io-stream");
    let http = require("http").createServer(app);
    const routes = require("routes");
    let io = require("socket.io")(http);
    routes(app, __dirname);
    http.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("app listening on port ", 3000);
    });
    io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
        socket.on("joinRoom", (obj) => {
            let { name, stream } = obj;
            console.log(name, stream);
        });
    });
```

And the client:

```
 <video autoplay="true" id="video"></video>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", { transports: ['websocket'] });
        let name = prompt("Enter the room name");
        function wrongname() {
            name = prompt("Seriously? That's not a name! enter again!");
            validator();
        }
        function validator() {
            if (!name.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/)) {
                wrongname();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        //validator();
        let video = document.getElementById('video');
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: true
                })
                .then((stream) => {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    console.log(stream);
                    socket.emit("joinRoom", {
                        name: name,
                        stream: stream
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("You choose to turn off your video and audio", error);
                    //location.replace('/');
                })
        }
    </script>
```

But the server in the console is outputting empty stream:

```
app listening on port  3000
John {}
Alex {}
```

Why is the stream working on the video element but not passing the stream to the server as  "{}" ?